# Clear phantomjs cache on ubuntu

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, caching, phantomjs

I'm running ubuntu and corrupted my phantomjs cache. Some of the cached data is causing my unit tests to fail. How do I clear the cache?

Comment: I really hope you're not going to create a self-answer for Windows too. If you want then you really should create one for Linux/Mac/Windows in a single Q&A. We don't need this fragmentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rm -rf ~/.qws/share/data/Ofi\ Labs/PhantomJS/
```